# web.config: hide file extension and force to add trailing slash at end of url

Tags: url, redirect, iis, url-rewriting, web-config

I am stuck to rewrite and redirect rules in **webconfig**.
I want to **remove file extension and forcibly adding trailing slash at end of URL** I got a code but it works with file extension when I tried the same code with hiding file extension, it takes me to 404 page.
FYI - **http://example.com/about-us.php/** is working fine

Expected result - **http://example.com/about-us/** redirect to 404 page.

Please tell me the code which hides file extension and adds trailing slash at the same time using the web.config file.

I have applied some rules which I listed below, trailing slash is added but it takes me to the **http://example.com/about-us.php/** when I entered put **http://example.com/about-us** in browser

Just FYI - it is working fine with http://example.com/about-us/ but I want **http://example.com/about-us** URL to **http://example.com/about-us/**

Here is my rule list:

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom"><!-- For non-managed files -->
        <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
        <error statusCode="404" path="/404.php" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    </httpErrors>
<rewrite>
    <rules>

        <rule name="Add trailing slash rule 1" stopProcessing="true">  
            <match url="(.*[^/])$" />  
            <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />  
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" /> 
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="{R:1}.php/" /> 
        </rule> 
        <rule name="Add trailing slash rule 2" stopProcessing="true">  
            <match url="(.*[^/])" />  
            <conditions>  
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />  
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />  
            </conditions>  
            <action  type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.php/" redirectType="Permanent" />  
        </rule>
        <rule name="hide php extension" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^(.*)$" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.php/" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Can you please add rules, what you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use this rules:

```
<rules>
    <rule name="AddTrailingSlashRule" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*[^/])$" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}/" />
    </rule>  

    <rule name="hide php extension" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^(.*)/$" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.php" />
    </rule>
</rules>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   <rule name="Add trailing slash" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(.*)([^/])$" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="(.*?)\.[a-zA-Z]{1,4}$" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="{R:0}/" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```

RULE FOR IIS USERS : ADDING / TO All URL. Worked for all seo